# Assertions mismatch: -ea was not specified but -Dtests.asserts=true

Tags: eclipse, junit, lucene

When I run maven test, it works successfully.
However, with the same project in Eclipse, it shows the following error.

```
Assertions mismatch: -ea was not specified but -Dtests.asserts=true
```

What configuration should be added or changed?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the Eclipse project is not properly configured.

1. eclipse preference -> junit -> Add -ea checkbox enable.
2. right click on the eclipse project -> run as -> run configure -> arguments tab -> add the **-ea** option in vm arguments

Answer (score 1):

Lucene uses the system property `tests.asserts` to activate assertions [in its Ant `build.xml`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/09e73bb18e92c012d7954bb27221c851c0c0f857/lucene/common-build.xml#L129).

If you run it with through some other technique than through Ant, for example with Eclipe, it will pick up the mismatch ([in `TestRuleAssertionsRequired`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/8a9cf45ec24237b0c96a98b2c0ebba64620cd20c/lucene/test-framework/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/TestRuleAssertionsRequired.java#L34)).

Ensure that the values match by setting the same arguments in Eclipse's run configuration: `-ea -esa`.